# Using echo and read $variable not working in UNIX! (UNIX beginner!)

Tags: variables, unix

So I just started learning UNIX yesterday, and I'm trying to create a basic script that asks for your contact details (name, address, phone number), and then stores that into a file called details.out.

This is driving me NUTS! Its such an easy/basic thing, yet I cant do it, and I've been stuck on it for a solid hour now...

after much googling and searching, I still can't find the answer. So this is what I've done so far, and was wondering where I am going wrong!

```
echo Please type your first and last name
read $firstname $lastname
echo Please type in your address
read $address
echo Please type in your phone number
read $phone
echo Thank you very much!
echo The details have been stored in '"details.out"'
cat >> details.out <<EOF
Name: echo $firstname echo $lastname
Address: echo $address
Phone Number: echo $phone
EOF
```

When I read "details.out" it it displays as follows:
Name: echo
Address: echo
Phone Number: echo

ANY help would be appreciated! (and if you get try and point me in the right directions as opposed to straight up giving me the answer, I would appreciate that!)

P.S I'm using Putty if that helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- when you use `read` (or declaring variables), don't put $ sigil on the variable names
- when you display a variable, always put double quotes around : ex. `echo "$var"`
- when you use *here-doc*, no need to put `echo` command
- when you use echo, use quotes :

"Double quote" **every** expansion, and anything that could contain a special character, eg. "$var", "$@", "${array[@]}", "$(command)". Use 'single quotes' to make something literal, eg. 'Costs $5 USD'. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate that! I can finally move  forward now :D

Comment: The way to thanks on stackoverflow is to upvote/accept answers. post edited with more comments

Comment: Vote Up says I need 15 reputations, and I need to wait 5 minutes to tick the answer off!

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you put a `$` before a variable name, you're retrieving the current value of that variable. You don't want to do that in your `read` command. The variables are empty when the script starts, the empty values are put in place of the `$firstname` and `$lastname` and `read` is called with no arguments, causing it to read a line and discard it.

Setting a variable with assignment:

```
var=value
```

Setinng a variable with `read`:

```
read var
```

Neither of them use `$var` because they don't want to look at the current value, they want to replace it.

There's no need for those `echo`s in the heredoc either. They aren't in command position, so they'll just get copied as part of the input to `cat`.